# Which encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, urldecode

does anybody know in which way the string **'Krummh%C3%B6rn'** is encoded?

Plain text is "Krummhörn".

I need to decode strings like this one in Python and tried **urllib.unquote('Krummh%C3%B6rn')**
The result: **'Krummh\xc3\xb6rn'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's UTF-8 in URL encoding.

```
print(urllib.unquote('Krummh%C3%B6rn').decode('utf-8'))
```

prints the string as you'd expect it to look.

Answer (score 4):

You're halfway there. Take *that* result and decode it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)